# Translating code from matlab to c#

Tags: c#, matlab

I am trying to implement image noise reduction using MRF. I used this [article](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/AV0809/ORCHARD/). It also provides [this code in matlab](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/AV0809/ORCHARD/restore_image.html). I tried to rewrite it in c# to work with noised images with only blue channel like this[image: like this]

But after using my code I got only darker image. What am I doing wrong? Is it something in matlab that I didn't include in my code?
My code is:

```
public static Bitmap Process(Bitmap src, double covar, double max_diff, double weight_diff, int iterations)
{
    var buffer = new Bitmap[2];
    var b = new Bitmap(src.Width, src.Height, src.PixelFormat);
    for (var i = 0; i < src.Width; i++)
        for (var j = 0; j < src.Height; j++)
        {
            b.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(src.GetPixel(i, j).A, 0, 0, 0));
        }

    buffer[0] = src;
    buffer[1] = b;
    var s = 1;
    var d = 0;
    var vMax = (src.Width * src.Height) * (Math.Pow(256, 2) / (2 * covar) + 4 * weight_diff * max_diff);

    for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Iteration: " + i.ToString());
        if (s == 0) { s = 1; d = 0; }
        else { s = 0; d = 1; }
        for (var r = 0; r < src.Height - 1; r++)
            for (var c = 0; c < src.Width - 1; c++)
            {
                //val = red
                var vLocal = vMax;
                var minVal = -1;
                for (var val = 0; val < 255; val+=1)
                {
                    var V_Data = Math.Pow((val - src.GetPixel(r, c).B), 2) / (2 * covar); //r
                    var V_diff = 0;

                    if (r > 1)
                    {
                        V_diff = V_diff + (int)Math.Min((val - Math.Pow(buffer[s].GetPixel(r - 1, c).B, 2)), max_diff);
                    }

                    if (r < src.Height)
                    {
                        V_diff = V_diff + (int)Math.Min((val - Math.Pow(buffer[s].GetPixel(r + 1, c).B, 2)), max_diff);
                    }

                    if (c > 1)
                    {
                        V_diff = V_diff + (int)Math.Min((val - Math.Pow(buffer[s].GetPixel(r, c - 1).B, 2)), max_diff);
                    }

                    if (c < src.Height)
                    {
                        V_diff = V_diff + (int)Math.Min((val - Math.Pow(buffer[s].GetPixel(r, c + 1).B, 2)), max_diff);
                    }

                    var V_current = V_Data + weight_diff * V_diff;

                    if (V_current < vLocal)
                    {
                        minVal = val;
                        vLocal = V_current;
                    }
                }
                Color color = buffer[d].GetPixel(r, c); 
                var e = Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, minVal);
                buffer[d].SetPixel(r, c, e);
            }
    }
    return buffer[d];
}
```

Comment: your code is very messy in regards to formatting.. you have several nested for loops and you should format them properly for readability in regards to using the `for() { }` meaning wrap open and closing `{ }` properly.. secondly use the debugger and step through this code.. you can't expect anyone to step through all of this and figure out where you are going wrong.. try to narrow down / pinpoint where you think the issue is happening and notate that..

Comment: Thanks for reply. I cannot say that I totally understand what is going on in matlab program. It seems that it is operating with image in grayscale format, not RGB. I tried to simulate it using only blue channel, but got only darker image at the end. I spent around 5 hours and tried to use different parameters but it didn't help too. So I think that root of the problem is in my incorrect translation from matlab program. And I hope someone who is confident with matlab can send me in the right direction.